# Filtering points from 3D plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a function T that depends on 3 variables and I want to plot with mathplotlib. I created axis arrays and then created 3d meshgrids, I also created a 3D matrix that has the results of my function T using axis matrices, as follows:

```py
xhat = np.linspace(20.0, 95.0, num=4)
sd = np.linspace(0.1, 38.4, num=4)
x = np.linspace(20.0, 95.0, num=4)
M_X, M_Y, M_Z = np.meshgrid(xhat, sd, x)
    
T = []

for i in range(len(xhat)):
    _fd = []
    for j in range(len(sd)):
        _sd = []
        for k in range(len(x)):
            _T = T(x[k], xhat[i], sd[j])
            _sd.append(_T >= CheckT(xhat[i]))
        fd.append(sd)
    T.append(fd)

T = np.array(T)
T = np.array([1 if _tt == True else 0 for _tt in np.ravel(T)]).reshape(M_X.shape)
```

After creating M_X, M_Y, M_Z and T, I plot them using colored scatter plot (red ones are zeros and green ones are ones):

[image: plot]

What I want to do is to remove all points except the first green point in Z axis but I can't figure out how to deal with the meshes.

Edit:
The function `CheckT()` returns a minimum value that I use to determine if the point should be green or red.

Here is my plotting code as requested. The function `rect_prism()` simply draws the gray 3d rectangles with given points on the plot.

```py
fig = plt.figure(dpi=120)
cmap = ListedColormap([[1,0,0], [0,1,0]])

ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(M_X, M_Y, M_Z, c=T, cmap=cmap, alpha=1, linewidths=1, edgecolors='k')
rect_prism(ax, [20, 95], [0.1, 38.4], [20, 95])

plt.show()
```

So, the complete code is:

```py
def CheckT(XHAT):
    if XHAT <= 42.5:
        return 51.0
    elif XHAT <= 47.5:
        return 49.0
    elif XHAT <= 52.5:
        return 47.0
    elif XHAT <= 57.5:
        return 45.0
    elif XHAT <= 62.5:
        return 43.0
    elif XHAT <= 70.0:
        return 41.0
    elif XHAT <= 80.0:
        return 39.0
    return 37.0

xhat = np.linspace(20.0, 95.0, num=4)
sd = np.linspace(0.1, 38.4, num=4)
x = np.linspace(20.0, 95.0, num=4)
M_X, M_Y, M_Z = np.meshgrid(xhat, sd, x)
    
T = []

for i in range(len(xhat)):
    _fd = []
    for j in range(len(sd)):
        _sd = []
        for k in range(len(x)):
            _T = T(x[k], xhat[i], sd[j])
            _sd.append(_T >= CheckT(xhat[i]))
        fd.append(sd)
    T.append(fd)

T = np.array(T)
T = np.array([1 if _tt == True else 0 for _tt in np.ravel(T)]).reshape(M_X.shape)

fig = plt.figure(dpi=120)
cmap = ListedColormap([[1,0,0], [0,1,0]])

ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(M_X, M_Y, M_Z, c=T, cmap=cmap, alpha=1, linewidths=1, edgecolors='k')
rect_prism(ax, [20, 95], [0.1, 38.4], [20, 95])

plt.show()
```

Comment: You forgot to show the plotting code

Comment: What is `CheckT`? Please post a [mcve]

Comment: @MadPhysicist `CheckT` is a function that returns a minimum value that I check to determine if the point should be green or red. It basically returns a minimum value depending on xhat.

About plotting code, it doesn't matter since I don't want to change the plot, I want to change the points, removing every point ecept the first green in Z axis. So I believe the operation that has to be mad should be before plotting, not while.

Comment: Yet, the plotting code would be useful to **us** to check if our potential solutions are working as expected ;)

Comment: @mozway, I updated the question with requested code :)